# Windows 8.1 cannot connect to one specific device on LAN

Tags: networking, router, windows-8.1, printer, arp

I just changed out an old Linksys WRT54GS wireless router for a TP-Link TL-WR841N wireless router.  I immediately flashed the router to use DD-WRT.

Everything went seamlessly except that my Windows 8.1 desktop can no longer see my Brother HL-2270DW network printer.  The printer has a reserved DHCP address of 192.168.1.200 on my local network.  I can reach the printer's web interface from Google Chrome on my Android device and from my Windows 7 laptop by simply entering the IP address in the browser's address bar. I can print to the printer from my Windows 7 laptop, also.

I cannot connect to the printer in any way from Windows 8.1.  I can connect to the Internet through the router on Windows 8.1.  I can connect to all other devices on the local network through Windows 8.1.

Both `tracert` and `ping` failed (using the known good reserved IP address of 192.168.1.200).  Initially they failed with a "Destination host unreachable" error.  It appeared there was an "Invalid" entry in the ARP table of the Win 8.1 machine.  I added a static ARP entry with the following command:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add neighbors Ethernet 192.168.1.200 00-1b-a9-12-34-56
```

Now `ping` and `tracert` return timeout errors instead of host unreachable errors.

Comment: This [question](http://superuser.com/q/588097/18255) appears similar to mine.  One solution might address both problems.  I think there's enough value in the different wording of the questions to leave them both in place, though.

Comment: This answer may solve my problem, but I'm not sure how to change or verify the settings in DD-WRT: http://serverfault.com/a/131163/25995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/972639/18255) to a related question solves this problem for me as well.  The short answer is it appears to be (what I would consider) a bug with DD-WRT's default configuration.  By default, DD-WRT does not enable communication between wired clients on a wireless router.  This "vlan" setting must be manually set via the following commands:

```
swconfig dev eth0 set enable_vlan 1
swconfig dev eth0 set apply
```