# Cannot delete entry from ARP cache

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, home-networking, arp

A picture's worth a thousand words:

[image: arp delete fails]

I'm running in an Administrator command prompt and trying to delete an invalid ARP entry.  It fails with no error or explanation.  Where do I go from here?

Comment: Have you tried a restart? Disable then re-enable the network card?

Comment: This problem has actually persisted through a clean re-install of a new operating system.  I asked a [more specific question](http://superuser.com/q/946138/18255) a few weeks ago, while I was still on Windows 8.1.  Since then I did an in-place upgrade to Windows 10 to get a valid Windows 10 key, then did a clean install of Windows 10 on a blank SSD.

Comment: What device is 102? Your current machine? And what device is 200?

Comment: I think the problem began when I changed out an old Linksys WRT54GS wireless router for a TP-Link TL-WR841N wireless router running DD-WRT.  I don't understand what role the router would be playing in wreaking havoc on my local ARP table.  Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way.

Comment: Look at your original specific question it appears the issue is the printer not your PC

Comment: Yes, 102 is the local device.  200 is a network printer (Brother HL 2270-DW).  I can access the printer web interface from other devices on the local network (my phone, a chromebook, a Windows 7 laptop, etc.) so I know it is available and working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27343/discussion-between-mwolfe02-and-davidpostill).